# my sphinx rtd themed documentation builds locally, fails building when posting to rtd?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

**OH GEEZ**
the extension is "myst**_**parser" and the library is myst-parser. The only thing better would be if somewhere else I had written mystParser...

**Thank you**

Steve - I don't use StackOverflow a lot.  Is there something I need to do to recognize? that you provided the answer?

`Add myst_parser to reqirements.txt. –` 
Steve Piercy
5 hours ago

sphinx-autobuild works great locally.  I send my project to github with sphinx documentation (as .md files) within the /docs folder.  Post to RTD web site.  Fails.  myst-parser is in requirements.txt.?

> sphinx.errors.ExtensionError: Could not import extension myst_parser (exception: No module named 'myst_parser')

## .readthedocs.yaml

```
# .readthedocs.yaml
# Read the Docs configuration file
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html for details

# Required
version: 2

# Set the version of Python and other tools you might need
build:
  os: ubuntu-20.04
  tools:
    python: "3.9"
    # You can also specify other tool versions:
    # nodejs: "16"
    # rust: "1.55"
    # golang: "1.17"

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
   configuration: docs/conf.py

# If using Sphinx, optionally build your docs in additional formats such as PDF
# formats:
#    - pdf

# Optionally declare the Python requirements required to build your docs
python:
   install:
   - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
```

## reqirements.txt

```
alabaster==0.7.12
Babel==2.11.0
bleach==5.0.1
build==0.9.0
certifi==2022.9.24
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
colorama==0.4.6
commonmark==0.9.1
cryptography==38.0.4
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.17.1
idna==3.4
imagesize==1.4.1
importlib-metadata==5.1.0
influxdb==5.3.1
jaraco.classes==3.2.3
jeepney==0.8.0
Jinja2==3.1.2
keyring==23.11.0
livereload==2.6.3
markdown-it-py==2.1.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
mccabe==0.7.0
mdit-py-plugins==0.3.1
mdurl==0.1.2
more-itertools==9.0.0
msgpack==1.0.4
myst-parser==0.18.1
packaging==21.3
paho-mqtt==1.6.1
pep517==0.13.0
pipreqs==0.4.11
pkginfo==1.9.1
pycodestyle==2.10.0
pycparser==2.21
pyflakes==3.0.1
Pygments==2.13.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.6
PyYAML==6.0
readme-renderer==37.3
requests==2.28.1
requests-toolbelt==0.10.1
rfc3986==2.0.0
rich==12.6.0
SecretStorage==3.3.3
six==1.16.0
snowballstemmer==2.2.0
Sphinx==5.3.0
sphinx-autobuild==2021.3.14
sphinx-rtd-theme==1.1.1
sphinx_design==0.3.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.5
tomli==2.0.1
tornado==6.2
twine==4.0.1
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.13
webencodings==0.5.1
yarg==0.1.9
zipp==3.11.0
```

## conf.py

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information
import os
import sys
# Add the code path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../code'))

project = 'GrowBuddies'
copyright = '2022, HappyDay'
author = 'HappyDay'
release = '2022.12.0'

# ignore files
exclude_patterns = ["py_env/*", '**/_*']

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'myst-parser', 'sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel', 'sphinx_design']
# Make sure the target is unique
autosectionlabel_prefix_document = True


# Include methods that start with an _
napoleon_include_private_with_doc = True

# Add Myst extensions
myst_enable_extensions = ["colon_fence", "html_image"]

# Needed for font awesome support using the sphinx-design extension.
html_css_files = [
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css"
]

# Ignore documentating these files.
autodoc_mock_imports = ['influxdb', 'paho']

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

Comment: You have to show your config file as part of the question, https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/reproducible-builds.html#using-a-configuration-file

Comment: Add `myst_parser` to `reqirements.txt`.

Comment: I did;  that's the weird part.  Thank you.

Comment: You need to specify `myst_parser` in conf.py (not `myst-parser`).

Comment: OH MY!  You are right.  Thanks so much.  I'd type more but I'm laughing too hard!!!

Comment: I posted this as an answer so you can accept it. This will help people arriving to this question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`myst-parser` is the name of the Python package. However, the name of the Python module once installed is `myst_parser`. You need to specify `myst_parser` in conf.py (not `myst-parser`).