# How to use the README.md file as homepage for shpinx readthedocs

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, toctree

I have a `README.md` file which contains general overview of the package, and would like to add that file as main homepage to my documentation using spinx, can you please tell me how can I add it to my `index.rst`? thanks in advance

#### index.rst

```py
my_apckage
==========

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   my_package.main_page
```

> PS: since I'm a beginner in Sphinx, I adpoted the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74642433/my-sphinx-rtd-themed-documentation-builds-locally-fails-building-when-posting-t) for `conf.py`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [include](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment) directive for this
like:

```
my_apckage
==========

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   my_package.main_page

.. include:: ../README.rst
```

If you have README in Markdown (which I believe is the case) you can do the following.
Also you will be needing an extension for parsing markdown. (I have used MyST)

```
.. include:: ../README.md
   :parser: myst_parser.sphinx_
   :start-after: <!-- index.rst content start -->
```

You can also configure how much to include a file
For example you can see my [index.rst](https://github.com/ABD-01/Flask-Protobuf/blob/master/docs/index.rst?plain=1#L29) file for [this](https://abd-01.github.io/Flask-Protobuf/) project. The index.html is 99% README.md

Comment: thanks for your answer, while it successfully adds the README file, it adds it after the contents in the same page, and not as a Home page.

Comment: Move the include directive to where you want to show the README.md contents in index page.